# Rigging the upper arm

Tags: rigging

In a picture like that, what are the double circles, blue and red, in the upper arm? I can't understand . . . Is a bone with a custom shape? Does it effect the mesh? How can i realize it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've selected a bone:

[image]

What you see is the rotation manipulator:

[image]

your animation shows a rotation around the y-axis.